# Sklearn on aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn, aws-lambda

I want to use sklearn on AWS lambda. sklearn has dependencies on scipy(173MB) and numpy(75MB). The combined size of all these packages exceeds AWS Lambda disk space limit of 256 MB.

How can I use AWS lambda to use sklearn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This guy](https://serverlesscode.com/post/scikitlearn-with-amazon-linux-container/) gets it down to 40MB, though I have not tried it myself yet.

The relevant [Github repo](https://github.com/ryansb/sklearn-build-lambda).

Comment: Thanks @Entropic Thunder

Comment: I see this repo is not maintained, and doesn't support new versions of python. Are there updated ways to get the same result?

Comment: I don't know of one.  This question is pretty old-- I don't have a lot of experience with stack overflow but this really shouldn't be the marked answer anymore.

Answer (score 0):

there is a two way to do this 
**1) installing the modules dynamically 

2)  aws batch**

**1) installing the modules dynamically**

```
def lambdahandler():
   #install numpy package 
   # numpy code 
   #uninstall numpy package
   ## now install Scipy package 
      # execute scipy code
```

or vice versa depends on your code

**2) using Aws batch**
This is the best way where you don't have any limitation regarding Memory space. 
just you need to build a `Docker` image and need to write an all required packages and libraries inside the `requirement.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do the same, and it was very difficult indeed. I ended up buying this layer that includes scikit-learn, pandas, numpy and scipy.

https://www.awslambdas.com/layers/3/aws-lambda-scikit-learn-numpy-scipy-python38-layer

There is another layer that includes xgboost as well.